# Time series weird interpolations in python matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, time-series

I am new to matplotlib and am working with data that only has values in the `9` to `5` interval, Monday through Friday.

When I try to plot the data, I notice there are interpolations between the missing values between `17:00` and `9:00` in the next workday, due to matplotlib's sudden inclusion of the missing datetime.

My goal here is to:

1) add vertical dotted lines at the left side of the discontinuities

2) remove the interpolations

---

The following is a snippets of the code I am working with. The code will generate two plots.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from datetime import datetime


x_var1= pd.date_range(datetime(2014, 1, 14, 9, 0),datetime(2014, 1, 21, 17, 0),
                   freq="30min",
                   tz= 'US/Pacific',
                   closed= 'left'
                   )

x_var1 = x_var1[x_var1.dayofweek < 5]
x_var1= x_var1[x_var1.indexer_between_time('9:00','17:00', include_end= False)]
x_var1= x_var1[x_var1.hour != 12]

np.random.seed(0)
y_var2= np.random.normal(loc= 40, scale= 4.4, size= len(x_var1))
fig, ax= plt.subplots(nrows= 2, ncols= 1)

ax[0].plot(x_var1, y_var2)
ax[0].set_title("This plot has extra interpolation that needs to be removed and needs vertical dotted lines for discontinuities")


x_var2= np.arange(len(x_var1))
ax[1].plot(x_var2, y_var2)
ax[1].set_title("this plot only needs correct xaxis and added vertical dotted lines for discontinuities")

plt.show()
```

My goal is to make the top plot looks like the bottom one, except the bottom plot needs to change its xaxis to the top plot's xaxis and add the vertical dotted lines at the left side of the discontinuities. I am still new to the world of matplotlib so I am not sure how to do these things pythonically and efficiently.

---

EDIT: changed the example dataset to a more random one that better reflects the actual problem. Also included a lunchbreak so there will be missing data between `12:00` and `12:59`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, is this what you're looking for?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_var1= pd.date_range(pd.to_datetime('2014-01-14 09:00:00'), pd.to_datetime('2014-01-21 17:00:00'),
                   freq="30min",
                   tz= 'US/Pacific',
                   closed= 'left'
                   )

x_var1 = x_var1[x_var1.dayofweek < 5]
x_var1= x_var1[x_var1.indexer_between_time('9:00','17:00', include_end= True)]
x_var1= x_var1[x_var1.hour != 12]

np.random.seed(0)
y_var2= np.random.normal(loc= 40, scale= 4.4, size= len(x_var1))

df = pd.DataFrame(index=x_var1, data=y_var2)

# mpl won't plot between nan values
df[(df.index.hour == 17) & (df.index.minute == 0)] = np.nan
df[(df.index.hour == 9) & (df.index.minute == 0)] = np.nan
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot(ax=ax, legend=False)
df[(df.index.hour == 9) & (df.index.minute == 0)] = 0

# we know the discontinuities occur at the end of the days
[plt.axvline(d, ls='--') for d, v in list(zip(df.index, df.iloc[:, 0])) if pd.isnull(v)]
```

[image]

Comment: Really appreciate your time and effort. This is much closer to what I am looking for. I slowly realized what I aim to do in matplotlib is pretty advanced.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do this. Not sure if I put the vertical lines on the correct discontinuities, but hopefully you get the idea:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_var1= pd.date_range(pd.to_datetime('2014-01-14 09:00:00'), pd.to_datetime('2014-01-21 17:00:00'),
                   freq="30min",
                   tz= 'US/Pacific',
                   closed= 'left'
                   )
x_var1 = x_var1[x_var1.dayofweek < 5]
x_var1= x_var1[x_var1.indexer_between_time('9:00','17:00', include_end= True)]

df = pd.DataFrame(index=x_var1, data=[np.nan]*len(x_var1))
df.iloc[0, 0] = 0
df.iloc[-1, 0] = 100
# to get line with "slope of 1"
df = df.interpolate(method='time')

# mpl won't plot between nan values
df[(df.index.hour == 17) & (df.index.minute == 0)] = np.nan
df[(df.index.hour == 9) & (df.index.minute == 0)] = np.nan
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot(ax=ax, legend=False)
df[(df.index.hour == 9) & (df.index.minute == 0)] = 0

# we know the discontinuities occur at the end of the days
[plt.axvline(d, ls='--') for d, v in list(zip(df.index, df.iloc[:, 0])) if pd.isnull(v)]
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: The actual data I am running is a vector of random values rather than a nice straight lines with slope of 1. I am not sure if this works on my actual data.